# Customizing completion in Prezto ZSH for git function

Tags: git, zsh, prezto

I recently switched from bash to zsh and am using Prezto for basic setup. For a long time I've used this function:

```
function g() {
  if [[ $# > 0 ]]; then
    git $@
  else
    git status
  fi
}
```

This allows me to use `g` for `git status` or `g <command>` for any other git action.

The Prezto git module had an alias that was overriding my function
`alias g='git'`

So I commented this out and my function worked as expected. However the problem comes in when I need tab completion.

ex:

I have thus far been unable to marry using my function with the git completion modules so that I can do things like `g checkout aw-<tab>` and have it show me the branch options.

I had this working fine in bash and would love to be able to have similar functionality in zsh.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
compdef g=git
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#copying-completions-from-another-command)